# emberJS: Is it possible to use helpers in Component/controller Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, helper

If I create a helper, then it's straight forward to use it in HBS files.
But can I use it in JS files of a controller or a component?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. you can. assume you got format-css helper, then you can import it like 
`import { formatCss } from 'app-name/helpers/format-css';` and you can use it inside js file `formatCss(['argument1'])`

Comment: very helpful, thank you @Ember-Freak!
i was looking for a solution to this use case for ages.

i am adding my use-case, as additional example: inlining SVG into an ember-template, for rendering into Leaflet.js map.

libs used: [svg-jar](https://github.com/ivanvotti/ember-svg-jar) and Leaflet.js

`import svgJar  from 'your-app-name/helpers/svg-jar';` then
```L.divIcon({ html: `<div> ${ svgJar.compute(["name-of-svg"], { class: "custom-icon-svg" }).string } </div>` });```

Answer (score 0):

In Ember 1.x, instead of:

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(someArg){
  //do something
});
```

Export the function separately with a named export:

```
//app_name/helpers/some-helper.js
export function someFn(someArg) {
    //do something 
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(someFn);
```

This way, the helper is properly defined to be used in templates, but in any js file, you import the named helper function (not the default export):

```
import { someFn } from 'app_name/helpers/some-helper';
someFn()
```

In 2.16, from the docs you see they recommend such exporting (with a different mechanism for creating helpers):

```
import { helper } from "@ember/component/helper"

export function formatCurrency([value, ...rest]) {
  let dollars = Math.floor(value / 100);
  let cents = value % 100;
  let sign = '$';

  if (cents.toString().length === 1) { cents = '0' + cents; }
  return `${sign}${dollars}.${cents}`;
}

export default helper(formatCurrency);
```